# How can you tell if you go on to the next steps of hiring after a phone interview?

Tags: interviewing

I had a phone interview which lasted 30 minutes for an industry Analyst position.Before the interview started, she said she is still interviewing candidates for the position. From what I understand, people say if your interview goes overtime, then it is likely that you made it to the next step, which is an in-person interview. The last couple of questions I was asked was about my "salary expectations", "if I am seeking a visa sponsorship", and "when can I start". After the interviewer asked questions, she then asked if I had any questions. I asked 2 questions, and then asked what are the next steps in the process. She said I can expect to hear from them in 2 weeks. If the phone interview lasted exactly 30 minutes, does that mean I am not going on to the next steps of interviewing in-person? How can you tell if you got the job?

Comment: They'll let you know sometime in the next 2 weeks (or more). There's nothing more anyone on this board will be able to tell you. In the meantime, keep sending out resumes and taking interviews until you accept an offer.

Answer (score 8):

> How can you tell if you got the job?

You can't.

> From what I understand, people say if your interview goes overtime, then it is likely that you made it to the next step, which is an in-person interview.

If an interviewer ends an interview "on time" it could be that they have a meeting they have to attend or maybe the room the meeting is in has a reservation for that time.

Honestly, I think you're reading too much into things. You'll find out when you find out.

Since you got to a phone interview, common courtesy would suggest that you'll probably receive some sort of notification either way.

Answer (score 1):

Interviewers are specifically trained so as to not give hints as to whether or not the applicant "passed".  I've had the opposite situation as you, where I had an interview once which went overtime, and I was specifically told in the feedback from the company, that the interviewer felt I didn't respect their time and that's why they failed me.  You really can never tell.

The rule of thumb is to always assume you failed.  It sounds depressing, but it's really the safest.  As soon as you're off the phone with one company, start calling the next one (or accepting calls, or sending out more resumes, whatever you like).  Then you'll always have a head start on resuming your job search when the negative feedback comes back, and if positive feedback comes back you can always cancel your other interviews.

The only point at which you can stop job searching is when you are told you have an offer on the way.  At that point, my rule is that I continue finishing up any outstanding interviews I have until the offer letter is signed and countersigned (there are lots of posts here about "I was promised an offer but never received it", so you're not done yet), but stop accepting new ones.  That's just my preference though; interviewing is time consuming for both parties so it's a waste of both people's time if you're expecting an offer letter and another company wants to put you through a phone screen.

Comment: "Interviewers are specifically trained so as to not give hints as to whether or not the applicant "passed"" <- the only training I've had in 15+ years of interviewing is some diversity and inclusion training.

Comment: OK fine, *some* interviewers are trained as such.  I went through interview training and it was mentioned.  We weren't trained, so much as instructed, to not give such signals.  But anyway it is part of the curriculum, at least in that company.